Extracting all characters from the beginning of a string through the first 5 digits of last portion of string?
I am working in R with some really messy address data and have been able to solve every issue except one. At the end of the address string, where the zip code is -- there is often 1, 2, or 3 additional digits which I need to remove (when they are present). I cannot just substring the field as the number of trailing digits varies, so it appears I need a regex solution.
Here are some examples of how the addresses currently look:
"3660 Nogales St West Covina, CA, 9179266"
"6666 W Peoria Ave #106 Glendale, AZ, 85302174" 
"10391 Friars Rd San Diego, CA, 9212051"
"7950 E Mississippi Ave Suite F Denver, CO, 8024766"
"1079 S Federal Blvd Denver, CO, 8021956"
"1420 Saratoga Ave San Jose, CA, 9512948"

I've tried several things which resulted in unexpected outputs. The most recent attempt, which I thought would work, is greedy matching on commas and extracting the 5 digits following the final comma group.
This is the code I used:
str_extract_all(df$address, "^\\w+(?:,\\w+)*,\\d{5}") but this turns the string into character(0) when I expected it to return the addresses less the trailing digits. So, I expect there is an issue with the code rather than the solution itself.
I am still learning regex and consider myself a beginner, so I may be making a trivial mistake or missing a feature that is critical to the code working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Simply convert matches of the regular expression (?<=\b\d{5})\d+$ to empty strings.  You may need to specify perl=TRUE. The regex reads, "Match one or more digits at the end of the string (\d+$) provided it is preceded by five digits (\d{5}) that are preceded by a word boundary (\b), (?<=...) being a positive lookbehind. Demo

Alternatively, match ^.*(?<=\b\d{5})(?=\d*\s*$). This regex reads, "Match any number of characters from the start of the string (^.*), provided the last five characters are digits preceded by a word boundary ((?<=\b\d{5})) and are followed by zero or more digits followed by zero or more whitespaces at the end of the string ((?=\d*\s*$)), (?=...) being a positive lookahead. Demo

Thank you! These are helpful, especially with understanding exactly how the lookbehind/lookahead logic works.

Using a capture group with sub
sub("(, \\D{2}, \\d{5}).*$", "\\1", dat)
[1] "3660 Nogales St West Covina, CA, 91792"          
[2] "6666 W Peoria Ave #106 Glendale, AZ, 85302"      
[3] "10391 Friars Rd San Diego, CA, 92120"            
[4] "7950 E Mississippi Ave Suite F Denver, CO, 80247"
[5] "1079 S Federal Blvd Denver, CO, 80219"           
[6] "1420 Saratoga Ave San Jose, CA, 95129"

with str_replace
library(stringr)

str_replace(dat, "\\d+$", \(x) substr(x, 1, 5))
[1] "3660 Nogales St West Covina, CA, 91792"          
[2] "6666 W Peoria Ave #106 Glendale, AZ, 85302"      
[3] "10391 Friars Rd San Diego, CA, 92120"            
[4] "7950 E Mississippi Ave Suite F Denver, CO, 80247"
[5] "1079 S Federal Blvd Denver, CO, 80219"           
[6] "1420 Saratoga Ave San Jose, CA, 95129"

A working str_extract approach looks similar to the base R sub
str_extract(dat, ".*, \\D{2}, \\d{5}")

Data
dat <- c("3660 Nogales St West Covina, CA, 9179266", "6666 W Peoria Ave #106 Glendale, AZ, 85302174", 
"10391 Friars Rd San Diego, CA, 9212051", "7950 E Mississippi Ave Suite F Denver, CO, 8024766", 
"1079 S Federal Blvd Denver, CO, 8021956", "1420 Saratoga Ave San Jose, CA, 9512948"
)


Thank you! This worked perfectly, and also helped give me some valuable insight I can use going forward. Much appreciated.
